# add key=value to a hash inside Rails without having to modify Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, key

I have an array of objects (hash) and I want to add a new key to the list of objects, iterating with .each method on it.

```
myArray = [];
@VARIABLE.each_with_index do |ITEM, index|
  myArray << ITEM
  myArray[:key]="value"
end
```

but Rails keeps returning me the error **can't write unknown attribute `key`**

I don't wanna modify Rails Model structure... I'm basically creating a helper array of objects to loop them in a JS React component in the view...

(JS dev here)

Comment: You can't do that in ruby, set an arbitrary key/value on an array. You can't do it in json either. So if tagging an array itself actually is what you want to do, you'll have to do it entirely in javascript.

Comment: I basically want to create a helper array of objects. adding a new item key/value to it.

Comment: If you want to add an item, add an item (with `<<`, `push` or maybe a few other methods)

Answer (score -1):

obj.attributes.merge({key:value}) solved the problem.